# How to set auto settle flag to MULTI in realex/global pay?

Tags: payment-gateway, realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I've gone through their documentation and it says to set Auto Settle Flag as MULTI. But there is no such parameter in the PHP SDK library.

[From their documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTiza.png)

How to set auto settle flag to MULTI in HPP?

I've also added the code sample below:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Address;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Enums\AddressType;
use GlobalPayments\Api\ServicesConfig;
use GlobalPayments\Api\HostedPaymentConfig;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\HostedPaymentData;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Enums\HppVersion;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\ApiException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Services\HostedService;

// configure client, request and HPP settings
$config = new ServicesConfig();
$config->merchantId = "MerchantId";
$config->accountId = "internet";
$config->sharedSecret = "secret";
$config->serviceUrl = "https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay";

$config->hostedPaymentConfig = new HostedPaymentConfig();
$config->hostedPaymentConfig->version = HppVersion::VERSION_2;
$service = new HostedService($config);

// Add 3D Secure 2 Mandatory and Recommended Fields
$hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData();
$hostedPaymentData->customerEmail = "james.mason@example.com";
$hostedPaymentData->customerPhoneMobile = "44|07123456789";
$hostedPaymentData->addressesMatch = false;

$billingAddress = new Address();
$billingAddress->streetAddress1 = "Flat 123";
$billingAddress->streetAddress2 = "House 456";
$billingAddress->streetAddress3 = "Unit 4";
$billingAddress->city = "Halifax";
$billingAddress->postalCode = "W5 9HR";
$billingAddress->country = "826";

$shippingAddress = new Address();
$shippingAddress->streetAddress1 = "Apartment 825";
$shippingAddress->streetAddress2 = "Complex 741";
$shippingAddress->streetAddress3 = "House 963";
$shippingAddress->city = "Chicago";
$shippingAddress->state = "IL";
$shippingAddress->postalCode = "50001";
$shippingAddress->country = "840";

try {
   $hppJson = $service->authorize(19.99)
      ->withCurrency("EUR")
      ->withHostedPaymentData($hostedPaymentData)
      ->withAddress($billingAddress, AddressType::BILLING)
      ->withAddress($shippingAddress, AddressType::SHIPPING)
      ->serialize();      
   // TODO: pass the HPP JSON to the client-side    
} catch (ApiException $e) {
   // TODO: Add your error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment it does not appear that multi-capture is supported by the Global Payments PHP SDK.

https://github.com/globalpayments/php-sdk/blob/master/src/Gateways/RealexConnector.php#L163

Multi-capture functionality is being added however and will be available at some point in the future.

Until this time, please feel free to update a fork of the repo, to suit your needs. We're adding a mutli-capture boolen flag on the base level TransactionBuilder and using this flag through the AuthorizationBuilder into the processTransaction method of the RealexConnector. I would then check the flag, and set auto-settle to "MULTI", if not set then follow the existing logic for the 0/1 values.